# Why you use supertab plugin of vim?

Tags: vim

I just played around with supertab plugin, but I didn't find anything particular. I feel basically the vim built-in 'complete' feature can do the same thing with `<c-n>` and `<c-p>`. Why supertab gained so much stars? I guess there must be something I wasn't ware of...

Comment: Like all Vim plugins, Supertab has a description of what it does on its page and/or documentation. If you had taken the time to read either of those you would have answered your question. Hint, it does *a lot more* than `<C-n>`/`<C-p>`.

Comment: I'm deleting this superfluous question.

Comment: I actually has same confusion, even through I've read the README in supertab repo, I still don't know why I need it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Supertab indeed uses the same built-in insert-mode completion as `<C-n>` / `<C-p>` (or variations thereof like *omnicompletion*, depending on the configuration). It's just that many users find the overloaded behavior of the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key (complete vs. inserting a Tab character) useful, probably because this is a common function in many IDEs and other editors.

If you already have the `<C-n>` completion ingrained in your finger memory, there's little to be gained from Supertab.